# Angular.js: Storing variable from http.get request to use globally in different $scope function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, infinite-scroll, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement Infinite scroll in my Ionic/Cordova mobile application. My **nextBatch** variable holds the url to the next set of objects I need to fetch once the user hits the bottom of the page. The only problem is, when I try to access it in my **loadMoreData()** functions it comes out as undefined. I've tried using $rootScope only to get the same result. Any ideas how I should handle this?

Thanks!

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope,Model) {

        var nextBatch; //holds the url of the next batch
        $scope.model = []; //used in ng-repeat

        //loads an array of 5 objects
        Model.getAll().success(function(model){
            nextBatch        = model.meta.next; //for infinite scrolling 
            $scope.model     = model.objects; 
        })

        $scope.loadMoreData = function() {
            if (nextBatch !== undefined) {
                Model.getMore(nextBatch).then(function(model){
                   $scope.model.push(favours);
                   $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
                })      
            }
};

 })
```

Comment: Why not just set it to `$scope.whatever`?

Comment: I also did that, comes out as null, I think it has to do with asynchronous behavior, but I am not sure

Comment: It looks like loadMoreData is called "too soon", I mean : when getAll is not yet resolved. You may start a promise before getAll, and condition the loadMoreData to the resolution of this promise. You can plunker it to have the code. Also, it looks like your infinite scroll is a 2 pages only : your are not setting back "nextBatch" after each getMore...

Comment: Hi @benek, yes I know I am not setting the nextBatch each time, it's just for testing purposes. Also, could you give me an example how I would set the promise in this context? I am still new to angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can make synchronizing your infinite scroll. I mean blocking the loadMore until the first call (getAll is finished).

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, Model, $q) {
  var nextBatch; //holds the url of the next batch
  $scope.model = []; //used in ng-repeat

  var defer = $q.defer();
  var promise = defer.promise;

  //loads an array of 5 objects
  Model.getAll().then(function(model){
      nextBatch        = model.meta.next; //for infinite scrolling 
      $scope.model     = model.objects;
      defer.resolve(model);
      return defer.promise;
  });

  $scope.loadMoreData = function() {
      promise.then(function(result){
          if(nextBatch !== "END"){
            Model.getMore(nextBatch).then(function(favours){
              angular.forEach(favours.objects, function(item){
                $scope.model.push(item);
              });
              nextBatch = favours.meta.next;
            });
          }    
      });
  };
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/qohKNUd48czYKASNqCVP